# Whirlpool Model 6065D mini split

Tags: wiring, heating

I purchased a new Whirlpool Model 6065 Mini-split in Mexico last year. The price was right.Installation manual is in Spanish and Whirlpool USA will offer no support. Manual appears to say power goes to inside head first and then to outside compressor. Some have said this is wrong and will blow the unit. Any experience/advise? Thanks. Max Boese

Comment: Is there an English version of the manual available on their website?

Comment: If not, do you know someone who can translate it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the compressor evaporator unit has the main power 240v and with inside units only need 120v for the fan. How are you going to pump the line set down? The compressor is probably charged but after the line set is brazed it needs to be pumped down to at least 500um and verify that it is holding at what ever base pressure is achieved. This removes the air a non compressible and any moisture in the open plumbing.  If the base pressure can not be achieved there is a leak or there still moisture in evaporator / line set. 
Allthough this is a DIY site most of the above work requires a EPA 608 certification. If the system holds more than 5 lbs it would require 2 of the 3ea  608 certifications with that in mind a certified tech should be hooking the system up.